# Best way to create child process in linux and handle possible failing

Tags: c++, linux, fork, exec

I have parent process, that have to create few children processes. Best way I found is using `fork` + `execl`. But then parent process need to know if `execl` of concrete child fails or not, and I don't know how to implement that.

```
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
           std::cout << "ERROR on fork." << std::endl;
        } if (pid == 0) {
           execl("/my/program/full/path", (char *)NULL);
           exit(1);
        }
        else {
            if (/*child's process execl fails*/) {
                std::cout << "it failed" << std::endl
            } else {
                std::cout << "child born" << std::endl
            }
        }
```

I think this idea is not good:

```
int status(0);
sleep(100);
int res = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
if (res < 0 && errno == 10) {
    std::cout << "it failed" << std::endl
} else {
    std::cout << "child born" << std::endl
}
```

because it's not good to hope that child process will die after 100 milliseconds, I want to know that for sure as only that will happens.

I also think that creation of shared_memory or special pipe connection for such check is a Cannon against Bees.

There have to be simple solution for that, that I just didn't found yet.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Just use `popen` and check the return value.

Comment: Let's say it's still alive, how can I be sure that execl didn't failed? Maybe it failed, and process is alive just because it didn't complete `exit(1)` instruction yet.

Comment: Do you want to check that your process was successfully *launched*, or that it *completed* and *returned a status of zero*? The two are quite different.

Comment: I want to check that `execl` didn't failed.

Comment: The problem is that `execl` doesn't return at all, if it succeeded. You can, however, use `popen` instead of `fork` and `exec`. You can then determine whether the executable was launched by testing the result of the `popen` call. It'll be `NULL` on failure, or a valid file descriptor otherwise.

Comment: The convention the shell uses when an `execve` fails is for the child to do `exit(127);`. Of course, 127 is a valid return code from any program. If you want something more robust, you'll need some shared data (maybe a file descriptor) that can be set by the child to indicate failure.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, that looks reasonable, but how can I get those 127? If parent process will start to `waitpid` for changing status, but `execve` was succeed, I will freeze parent process. If I will use `waitpid` with `WNOHANG`, I may call it before child process will come to `exit(127)`, even if it goes there and `execve` failed.

Comment: OK, I think what you want is to be able to tell whether the execl definitely succeeded or definitely failed, with the parent being delayed for the smallest amount of time necessary to make that determination. Is that correct?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes. I thought there have to be any generic solution..

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, for task I'm working on, I can wait a second before `waitpid` call,being 99% sure it's enough time for child process to exit, or use slow and vulnerable `popen`, but I want to know how to achieve that for sure and without bad tricks. 
Task becomes more interesting, if I can't change this binary "/my/program/full/path", so I can't send from it to parent process anything on success.

Comment: @Arkady Do all child processes running independent? I mean that the use case doesn't clear for me. For example you have to start 3 child processes, am I correct that all what you need just start all 3 and then wait for results? Or do you need something like a pipeline? Could you please describe it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general solution you can register signal handler (SIGUSR1) in the parent using sigaction().

In a child: unregister signal handler, if execl() call failed you need to send SIGUSR1 to the parent.

In the parent: Every child pid we will store in std::set. When all childs are created you just create a separate thread for tracking childs. In the thread function just call wait() and remove pid from the set. Another way to listen SIGCHLD signal (but it will lead to more complex solution, so if spawn another thread is an option I'd use thread).

When the set is empty we have done.

Comment: That looks like good generic solution. I thought about it without special signal, but with signal it even looks logically completed. Thank you.